# Tags for oil-coolant leak

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw that people use the tags "oil" and "coolant" to indicate an oil-coolant-leak question. Would something speak against replacing that with a new "oil-coolant-leak" tag?

Comment: We do have 'oil-leak' and 'coolant-leak', and just plain 'leak', aren't they enough?  Another tag seems excessive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise against it for the simple reason the meta provided by the [oil](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil) and [coolant](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coolant) tags would be lost to this new tag. There is a lot of cross over between the two when it comes to there being leaks one way or the other. By throwing out a new tag now, that meta data would be lost.

To my way of thinking, when you add a new tag, the idea is to broaden the scope of the meta data. For instance, we have a tag for [chevrolet](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevrolet) and one for [gmc](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmc) trucks. If we were to use these two tags in the way you want to move forward, it would be like creating a [chevrolet-gmc-truck](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chevrolet-gmc-truck) tag, which wouldn't really get us anywhere or improve the meta data. It would just confuse things. The two are related, but putting them together really doesn't help anything.

Also, as @Chenmunka states in the comments, another tag seems excessive to me as well. Would a new tag provide any more meta accuracy than the way it is? I don't really think so.